# I want to check whether my rows and columns are same

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to check whether row 1 is equal to column one and row two is equal to column 2 and so on. If a matrix is equal to its transpose.

I tried to solve the problem using the following code, but the function is returning none. Can some one help me with this

```
x = [[1, 2, 3],
     [2, 3, 4],
      [3, 4, 1]]

def rows(matrix):
    list = [val for val in matrix]
    list1 = [i for i in zip(*matrix)]
    if list == list1:
        return True
    else:
        return False

rows(x)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `zip` function returns a list of tuples:

```
>>> x = [[1, 2, 3],
         [2, 3, 4],
         [3, 4, 1]]
>>> zip(*x)
[(1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4), (3, 4, 1)]
>>> x == zip(*x)
False
```

A list isn't equal to a tuple, even if it has the same elements.  A list of lists isn't equal to a list of tuples, even if the inner lists/tuples contain the same elements.  You can do what you want easily, and you were close!

```
>>> x == [list(i) for i in zip(*x)]
True
```

Answer (score 2):

`zip` returns tuples, not lists:

```
>>> [val for val in x]
[[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 1]]
>>> [i for i in zip(*x)]
[(1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4), (3, 4, 1)]
```

And they don't compare equal to each other:

```
>>> [1,2,3] == (1,2,3)
False
```

Instead, you can simply return the results of the comparison after converting to lists:

```
>>> x == [list(i) for i in zip(*x)]
True
```

Comment: Well, that's an impressive near-simulpost.

Comment: Got it. I dont know whose answer to accept. @paidhima answer is similar to yours

Comment: @dangerous: in the case of two such similar posts, I'd probably accept the one by the user of lower rep because they have more to gain, which in this case is paidhima.

Comment: @paidhima: baji-naji, as they say.

Comment: x = [["cat", "dog", "fish"], ["dog", "dog", "fish"], ["fish", "fish", "cat"]]  what if my x value is characters?? what can I do in that case? how should I modify my code?

Comment: @dangerous: you don't need to modify your code at all.

Answer (score 2):

Use `map` to map the sublists to tuples and compare, mapping to tuple shoud also be more efficient than changing tuples to lists:

```
def rows(matrix):
    return zip(*matrix) == map(tuple, matrix)
```

Comment: Yes, your algorithm is noticeably faster. On my 2GHz machine running Python 2.6.6 I get: `python -m timeit -n 100000 -r 3 -s "x=[[1, 2, 3],[2, 3, 4],[3, 4, 1]]" "zip(*x) == map(tuple, x)"` 100000 loops, best of 3: 5.76 usec per loop. And `python -m timeit -n 100000 -r 3 -s "x=[[1, 2, 3],[2, 3, 4],[3, 4, 1]]" "x==[list(i) for i in zip(*x)]"` 100000 loops, best of 3: 6.95 usec per loop

Answer (score 0):

You can understand what is wrong with your program by running this:

```
x = [[1, 2, 3],[2, 3, 4],[3, 4, 1]]

def rows(matrix):
    list = [val for val in matrix]
    list1 = [i for i in zip(*matrix)]
    print list
    print list1
    if list == list1:
        return True
    else:
        return False

print rows(x)
```

Here `print list` prints list of lists, while `print list1` prints list of touples.

Since `lists` and `touples` are different, the program returns `False`.